# How to control pr2 head in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, pr2-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to control pr2's head (i.e., moving up and down, left and right) in simulation, but couldn't get it working. To this effort, I start with playing with controlling right gripper as in the tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BasicPR2Controls). However, publishing a command does not seem to work (?!). It did not change anything. Actually I do not know what to expect..

Can anyone give me some directions of controlling pr2's head? Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10019/how-to-control-pr2-head-in-gazebo/) by [roboren](https://answers.ros.org/users/609/roboren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2011-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you want to control the head of the PR2 you should send goals to the pr2_head_action (http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_head_action). The pr2_controllers and pr2_common_actions packages many of the basic actions available for controlling the PR2

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For moving the gripper, if you're running diamondback and newer, did you follow [this link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20gripper)?

For moving the head, check out [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20Head).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this teleop controller provides the functionality to control the head, either using joystick or keyboard [pr2_teleop_general](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_teleop_general)

---

Originally posted by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) with karma: 311 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1